# Text in Html does not show correctly

Tags: html, css, footer, sections

I am new to the html and css and i am trying to learn a few things. I am following a tutorial from Linda and i am stack. I did it again and again and it seems like the bug persists.

The paragraph or < p > contains some words. that the footer overlays. If if do not modify the margin of the footer, the footer will start after the navigation bar(now with the margin it starts 5% further). What i would like to do is to make the footer start after the paragraph.

Please give a helping hand. Thanks in advance. 
[HOW IT LOOKS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFWDt.png)
HTML CODE:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
h1 {
 font-size: 2em;
 font-family: league-gothic;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
}
h2 {
 font-family: bitter;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 1.2em;
}
nav {
 background-color: #222325;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-right: 5%;
}
footer {
 text-align: center;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 background-color: #222325;
 font-size: x-small;
 margin-top: 5%;
 margin-right: 5%;
 margin-bottom: 5%;
 margin-left: 5%;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}




body {
 font-family: source-sans-pro;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 200;
}
.assideLeft {
 width: 30%;
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-right: 2.5%;
 float: left;
}
.sectionRight {
 width: 50%;
 margin-left: 2.5%;
 margin-right: 5%;
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--The following script tag downloads a font from the Adobe Edge Web Fonts server for use within the web page. We recommend that you do not modify it.--><script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script><script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/source-sans-pro:n2:default;league-gothic:n4:default;bitter:n4:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<header>LADY M 
  <nav>Home About Fashion Contact </nav>
</header>
<aside class="assideLeft">
   <h1>Where fashion meets everyday standards.</h1>
</aside>

<section class="sectionRight">
 <h2>Woman News</h2>
<p>I am an economics student that is interested in fashion, mode, trending styles and woman's life style. I have a successful account at Polyvore, where I communicate with other people, check new trend, have fun and doing my part to make the world a more beautiful place.</p>
</section>

<footer>Copyright Alexandros Tsoskounoglou.</footer> 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Well, you're using the elements wrong (`<h1>` in an `<aside>`? Really?) - however, "it displays wrong" doesn't really help us. How do you want it to look? (BTW: `<aside>` is an inane idiotic element, which rarely, if ever, has any real use. While the same thing can be said about `<section>`, `<article>`, `<header>`, `<footer>` and `<nav>`, at least the last three ones have a little bit of meaning.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you define, precisely and concisely, what problem in the display you need help fixing? (“All of it” is not an OK answer.)

Comment: i would like the footer to NOT overlap the text under the woman's news. I would like the footer to start where the text or <p> ends. Thank you for your quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
clear:both;
```

on your footer. 
Here is full documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear

Comment: It seems like if fixes the problem. But a) I have no idea why.(please explain) b) the tutorial does not mention clear: both. What does clear both does. // The page in the tutorial was built with live / split edit in Dreamweaver. No code editing. Inserting elements and selectors was the main tools.  Again thank you for your time

Comment: An float property not only align element to the left or right but make it floating above other elements like a layer. Clear: both property remove floating from the next elements.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what youre looking for? Try removing

```
margin-left: 2.5%;
margin-right: 5%;
float: right;
```

under .sectionRight

```css
@charset "utf-8";
h1 {
 font-size: 2em;
 font-family: league-gothic;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
}
h2 {
 font-family: bitter;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 1.2em;
}
nav {
 background-color: #222325;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-right: 5%;
}
footer {
 text-align: center;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 background-color: #222325;
 font-size: x-small;
 margin-top: 5%;
 margin-right: 5%;
 margin-bottom: 5%;
 margin-left: 5%;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}




body {
 font-family: source-sans-pro;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 200;
}
.assideLeft {
 width: 30%;
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-right: 2.5%;
 float: left;
}
.sectionRight {
 width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--The following script tag downloads a font from the Adobe Edge Web Fonts server for use within the web page. We recommend that you do not modify it.--><script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script><script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/source-sans-pro:n2:default;league-gothic:n4:default;bitter:n4:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<header>LADY M 
  <nav>Home About Fashion Contact </nav>
</header>
<aside class="assideLeft">
   <h1>Where fashion meets everyday standards.</h1>
</aside>

<section class="sectionRight">
 <h2>Woman News</h2>
<p>I am an economics student that is interested in fashion, mode, trending styles and woman's life style. I have a successful account at Polyvore, where I communicate with other people, check new trend, have fun and doing my part to make the world a more beautiful place.</p>
</section>

<footer>Copyright Alexandros Tsoskounoglou.</footer> 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you for you time. It seems like omitting the width makes it worse for some unknown reason. Also clear: both works for some, also unknown reason. But again thank you for your time.

Comment: omitting the width would eliminate the element. It looks like kornelia's answer is simpler and probably a better approach though.

Answer (score 0):

```css
@charset "utf-8";
h1 {
 font-size: 2em;
 font-family: league-gothic;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
}
h2 {
 font-family: bitter;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 1.2em;
}
nav {
 background-color: #222325;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-right: 5%;
}
footer {
 text-align: center;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 background-color: #222325;
 font-size: x-small;
 margin-top: 5%;
 margin-right: 5%;
 margin-bottom: 5%;
 margin-left: 5%;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
    clear:both;

}




body {
 font-family: source-sans-pro;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 200;
}
.assideLeft {
 width: 30%;
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-right: 2.5%;
 float: left;
}
.sectionRight {
 width: 50%;
 margin-left: 2.5%;
 margin-right: 5%;
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--The following script tag downloads a font from the Adobe Edge Web Fonts server for use within the web page. We recommend that you do not modify it.--><script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script><script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/source-sans-pro:n2:default;league-gothic:n4:default;bitter:n4:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<header>LADY M 
  <nav>Home About Fashion Contact </nav>
</header>
<aside class="assideLeft">
   <h1>Where fashion meets everyday standards.</h1>
</aside>

<section class="sectionRight">
 <h2>Woman News</h2>
<p>I am an economics student that is interested in fashion, mode, trending styles and woman's life style. I have a successful account at Polyvore, where I communicate with other people, check new trend, have fun and doing my part to make the world a more beautiful place.</p>
</section>

<footer>Copyright Alexandros Tsoskounoglou.</footer> 
</body>

</html>
```